# Salesforce session timeout - "mouse shaker" option?

Tags: session, salesforce, timeout, user-management

If Salesforce session timeout is set to 15 min, and a user is typing in a textbox in a salesforce and hasn't saved in 15 min, Salesforce session timer does not reset without a save or ping back to server.

Is there a different option/workaround so that the timer resets if the user is actively typing/using a salesforce box but not saving?

Answer (score 0):

Did your company click Setup -> Session Settings -> Disable session timeout warning popup? It's org-wide but there's idea to upvote: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdb0bUAB/disable-session-timeout-warning-popup-option-for-individual-user

Alternatively you could try some home grown timeout warning, inject it into Utility Bar at bottom of the screen... Might be messy

Alternatively - consider moving over to Notes (ContentDocument / ContentNote objects), you can see they save the draft as you type.